# How to implement Login with Google through Firebase within a .NET MAUI application

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-signin, maui

I am developing a .NET MAUI app for use on iOS, Android, and Windows devices.

In general, I have found that the documentation on Firebase to be lacking when integrating within any .NET application.  In particular, given the quick rise of .NET Maui's popularity, I don't see any advice with regard to allowing my MAUI app to add Firebase authentication via Login with Google or Facebook.  Maybe the documentation hasn't caught up yet?

Here is a screenshot the the project settings in my Firebase project.

Do I need to configure an Android app and then an iOS here for Google login?

[image: Do I need to configure an Android app and then an iOS here for Google login?]

If there is anyone who has accomplished this for .NET MAUI and could provide some guidance, I'd be all ears.

I am currently following a Xamarin tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYMCrD9klA0

Comment: I have tried and the current status from google os it's not supported.   Your going to have a code it from the ground up yourself.  I tried my old xamarin code it didn't work

Comment: This NuGet will be able to help you: https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet. However, the only provider that is working is the default Email. You will have to create those for the other providers for each OS you're supporting.